# My text file will not read into the array

Tags: c#

THIS HAS BEEN ANSWERED.  I am relatively new to C# and am experiencing a problem. My program keeps throwing an error per my try catch. I have looked over everything and changed things, but nothing seems to work. The error is being thrown on line 49 (where the while loop for reading the text file takes place). Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue?? I know there may be some other issues with the min/max/average, but I can figure that out. I just really need someone to help me fix the reading of the file into the array.

The error code is: Input string is not in correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;

```
namespace Total_Sales_BBrantley
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Declare variable to hold the amount of sales

            // Declare a constant for the array size
            const int SIZE = 100;
            // Create an array for the sales
            double[] allSales = new double[SIZE];
            // Declare a variable for holding the total value of sales
            double total = 0.0;
            // Declare a variable to hold the average
            double average;
            // Declare a variable to hold the highest value
            double highest = double.MinValue;
            // Declare a variable to hold the lowest value
            double lowest = double.MaxValue;

            int count = 0;

            // Declare a StreamReader variable.
            StreamReader readFile;

            // Open the file and get a StreamReader object using a relative path
            readFile = File.OpenText("Sales.txt");

            while (!readFile.EndOfStream && count < allSales.Length)
            {
             ERROR ERROR ERROR: [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[   allSales[count] = int.Parse(readFile.ReadLine()); ]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
                // Increment count
                count++;


        } 

            // Close the file
            readFile.Close();

            lstSales.Items.Add("The file contains " + count + " items:");
            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
            {
                lstSales.Items.Add(allSales[index]);

            }



            // Display the total
            double sum = allSales.Sum();
            lblTotal.Text = sum.ToString();

            total += sum;
            average = total / allSales.Length;
            lblAverage.Text = average.ToString();

            for (int index = 1; index < allSales.Length; index++)
            {
                if (allSales[index] > highest)
                {
                    highest = allSales[index];
                }
                lblHighest.Text = highest.ToString();

            }
            for (int index = 1; index < allSales.Length; index++)
            {
                if (allSales[index] < lowest)
                {
                    lowest = allSales[index];
                }
                lblLowest.Text = lowest.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Display an error message on bad input from file 
            MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Error calculating the sales. ", ex.Message,     "\r\n", ex.StackTrace));
        }

    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Closes the application
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add details of error which you have, and point exact line which throws  this exception

Comment: Counld you format your code please and add the exact problem line number.

Comment: What Exception is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are using int.Parse instead of double.Parse.

Comment: It was as simple as that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is you problem:

```
allSales[count] = int.Parse(readFile.ReadLine());
```

Your array is a Double array, and you are assigning a field to an integer value.  Parse the the line to a Double instead of int.

```
allSales[count] = Double.Parse(readFile.ReadLine());
```